# Fixed element aligned left to main column

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if that can be done with pure CSS.
The site structure looks like this:

```html
<body style="text-align:center;">
  <div style="max-width:1000px; margin: 0 auto;" id="mainWraper">
    <div id="fixedBox" style="position:fixed; top:100px; left:0;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

What I want to do is make the fixedBox element to be displaed always 100px from the top screen and aligned to the left side of the mainWraper.
mainWraper is responsive with the max width - 1000px;

I know that it can be done with JS but can I do this also only with css?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Is the code you have mentioned above, not giving you the desired result?

Comment: you add position: relative to your mainWrapper  
And add pposition: absolute to your fixedBox
Then your top and left properties are aligned to that wrapper insted of the page.

Comment: if you can avoid it use a css class instead of inline-style

Comment: I need top property to be aligned to the browser window, and left to the main container

Answer (score 3):

If the width of the container is below `1000px` the box will be aligned left to the viewport. Otherwise, it will be aligned left to the container:

```
#fixedBox {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    /* move it back half the width of your mainWrapper */
    margin-left: -500px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 999px) {
    #fixedBox {
        left: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/fqjzmoxg/)

Comment: Sorry, mainWrapper max-width is 1000px, it is responsive. I've changed the question description

Comment: @abiku I've updated my answer and the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fqjzmoxg/). I hope it's suitable to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a margin to fixedBox rather then using fixed position:

```
#fixedBox{
  margin: 100px 0px 0px 0px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the grey box is your `fixedBox` and it will always be 100px from the top and aligned left to main column

```html
<body style="text-align:center;">
  <div style="width:1000px; margin: 0 auto; height:1000px; position: relative;" id="mainWraper">
    <div id="fixedBox" style="position:fixed; top:100px; left:0; width: 20px; height: 20px; background-color: #aaa;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

issues:

1. always give fixed element width and height
2. added `top: 100px` so that the `fixedBox` stays 100px from the top
3. give some height to the `mainwrapper`